# IBM MQ 8 .0.0.14 memory leak and eats all memory?

Tags: linux, ibm-mq

Pls help !
We use IBM MQ this is output dspmqver:

```
  Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.14
Level:       p800-014-200107.1
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.15.3-1-generic
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 802
LicenseType: Production
```

About at 1 -2 week we need reboot mq manager because its eat all our RAM. TOP output:

```
top - 09:08:52 up 55 days, 22:13,  2 users,  load average: 1,02, 0,66, 0,43
Tasks: 164 total,   1 running, 101 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,8 us,  1,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 96,3 id,  0,5 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,3 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem : 12296712 total,   151156 free, 11192404 used,   953152 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,        0 free,  2095100 used.   173800 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5946 mqm       20   0 5186568 1,619g 567820 S   1,0 13,8 267:47.39 amqzlaa0
19235 mqm       20   0 4663220 1,516g 394512 S   5,0 12,9 925:24.87 amqrmppa
 3180 mqm       20   0 5187452 1,400g 563312 S   1,0 11,9  37:46.55 amqzlaa0
20194 mqm       20   0 4644060 1,398g 393016 S   3,3 11,9 654:11.41 amqrmppa
19569 mqm       20   0 4644188 1,317g 397828 S   1,3 11,2 644:51.19 amqrmppa
24828 mqm       20   0 5186308 1,195g 562544 S   1,7 10,2  92:26.81 amqzlaa0
12922 mqm       20   0 5187712 1,160g 563500 S   1,0  9,9 300:29.25 amqzlaa0
  482 mqm       20   0 5187712 1,042g 552212 S   0,0  8,9 273:48.41 amqzlaa0
19367 mqm       20   0 5186308 773968 585808 S   0,7  6,3 143:51.83 amqzlaa0
19214 mqm       20   0 5187628 459176 454008 S   1,3  3,7 174:04.99 amqzlaa0
30683 mqm       20   0  634188 404700 380924 S   0,0  3,3   3:19.41 runmqchl
19204 mqm       20   0  547812 220656 219936 S   1,3  1,8  86:29.25 amqpcsea
11943 mq_expo+  20   0 1401016 203476 191800 S   0,0  1,7  17:18.51 mq_prometheus
19148 mqm       20   0 2511796 192916 192196 S   0,7  1,6 181:09.56 amqzmuc0
19135 mqm       20   0 1648540  86728  86500 S   0,0  0,7  29:16.12 amqzxma0
19176 mqm       20   0  873692  20104  19764 S   0,0  0,2   0:05.29 amqrrmfa
```

As  you can see most memmory usage is amq* process. But WHY ?
For solving this problem we install last patch - 14 , but its didnt help.
May by we has some wrong configure, or some thing else , i dont know. Pls if can help this problem.

I think that reboot manager every 2 week its wrong solution but what i can do else ?

Comment: I would check on the client application side as well. Connections/queues/topics are being closed when they are done with job. Not holding any queue manager resources when not required.

Comment: Open a case with IBM.  They will asked for some documentation, for example: logs,  a short trace,  stackit output, sigdump.  All of this can be gathered using `runmqras` into a single file to send them.

Comment: Shashi Thanks for answer ! How can i monitor this from server side ?

Answer (score 0):

I would be willing to bet that you have one or more applications that stay running and continually connect to the queue manager without ever disconnecting.

i.e.

- Applications starts
- connect to queue manager - 1st
- open queue
- get or put messages
- may or may not close the queue
- connect to queue manager - 2nd
- open queue
- get or put messages
- may or may not close the queue
- connect to queue manager - 3rd
- open queue
- get or put messages
- may or may not close the queue
- etc.

Use your MQ monitoring tool to review the channel status of the queue manager to find the rogue (bad) application.  Or you can use MQ Explorer or runmqsc i.e. 'DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*) CURSHCNV'.

Once you find the rogue application, remind the programmer that if an application connects to something then it must disconnect from it. And if an application opens something then it must close it.  I'm willing to bet that they will say "I thought it would automatically disconnect (or close) it".  Your reply will be: "No, it doesn't, please fix/update your code."

If you don't have an MQ monitoring tool, there are lots of them available.  Here's a list of commercially available [MQ tools](https://capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html).

Comment: Thanks  for answer ! for monitoring MQ we use mq_exporter + prometheus, i will check they and add comment if find this bad application.

Answer (score 0):

- You should have an amqzlaa0 thread per mqconnected application.
- You should have an amqrmppa thread for each active channel.

There are  3 channels which are using a lot of memory, so this looks like it is not just an application issue.

See [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT20636) link

Comment: IT20636 is fixed in 8.0.0.8, they stated they are at 8.0.0.14.